# self.column_name.to_date slow?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am wondering if this is a bug or just have to live with it?!

Running ruby 1.9.2 on windows (Rails 3.0.1). Checked changelog of newer version to see if something mentioned about it but couldn't find anything.

Sample:

```
def same_Day?
  self.from.to_date.eql?(self.to.to_date)
end
```

Is MUCH slower than

```
def same_Day?
  Time.at(self.from.to_i).eql?(Time.at(self.to.to_i))
end
```

Any clue why to_date need so much more time?

Comment: your second method won't work anyway, because it includes the time part, as the name suggests. `to_date` has never seemed slow to me.

Comment: Hard to setup a better example here. I have a few hundred appointments and move the content to ExtJS via a rest controller. there I use this same_day method, and in my sample I have resulting time difference in firebug from 2.5 seconds down to 1 second. Checked all other code and isolated this part.

Comment: What class is self.from and self.to?

Comment: Forgot to mention that self.from and self.to are datetime_from and datetime_to fields from a ms sql 2008 server. Maybe it is a matter of tinyTDS sql adapter ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the source code to find this out. Any datetime stored in database should get parsed and returned as `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`. This is what you get by calling `self.to`. `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`'s `to_date` methods is nothing else than `self.to.time.to_date`.

When you check out the `to_i` method, it is more complicated than the `to_date` method.

See https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb

Anyway. If you want to be 100 % sure which way is faster, you have to perform a benchmark test. My simple test I run only in the `rails console` shown that the first way should be faster than converting the dates to integer and then comparing them.